# How does webkitAnimation End work?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I am working with css3 and I am trying to call a function right after I play an animation using webkit rotation. However, the function is being called when the animation starts and not after it. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
function winPrize() {

    var prizesAvailable = []; 
    prizesAvailable.push({prize: "red", location: 2171.25, image: "red-prize"});
    prizesAvailable.push({prize: "blue", location: 2193.75, image: "blue-prize"});
    prizesAvailable.push({prize: "yellow", location: 2216.25, image: "yellow-prize"});
    prizesAvailable.push({prize: "orange", location: 2238.75, image: "orange-prize"});
    prizesAvailable.push({prize: "red", location: 2261.25, image: "red-prize"});

    var randomGenerator = Math.floor((Math.random()*6));


    var cssAnimation = document.createElement('style');
        cssAnimation.type = 'text/css';

    var rule1 = document.createTextNode('@keyframes spin-the-wheel {'+
                'from { transform: rotate(0deg); }'+
                'to { transform: rotate(' + prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].location + 'deg); }'+
                '}');
     var rule2 = document.createTextNode('@-webkit-keyframes spin-the-wheel {'+
                'from { transform: rotate(0deg); }'+
                'to { transform: rotate(' + prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].location + 'deg); }'+
                '}');
     cssAnimation.appendChild(rule1);
     cssAnimation.appendChild(rule2);
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssAnimation);

     var start = document.getElementById("wheelContainer");
     start.className = start.className + " containerSpin";

     start.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', 
             displayPrize(prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].image), false );
}

function displayPrize(prizes) {

    var prizeImage = document.getElementById(prizes);
    prizeImage.className = prizeImage.className + " show";

}
```

CSS:

```
.containerSpin {
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: spin-the-wheel;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin-the-wheel;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
start.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', 
    displayPrize(prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].image), false);
```

Note that you invoke `displayPrize(prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].image)` right away, however you need to pass function reference. Try this:

```
start.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    displayPrize(prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].image);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thankyou, That stopped the image displaying before the animation has ended. But the image does not display after the animation has ended either. Would you know why? Thanks.

Comment: Because you don't display it. Previously it was displayed because you called `displayPrize(prizesAvailable[randomGenerator].image);`. If you need to do it you can call this function again before setting `start.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', ...`.